# Djikstra on a multigraph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

I am having a problem when using a djikstra on a multigraph. I basically have a graph, that each node represents a stop and contains some information about the stop, including connections to the next stop (edges). The problem is that between two nodes, I have multiple connections (edges) which represents different buses that I can use to move to the next stop.

Example:
I can go from stop A to stop B using bus 1, bus 2, bus 3, etc.

It gives me a path, but is not the optimal due to choosing an incorrect bus.

I also have stops with the same name (which are stops with different directions).

My graph looks like:

```json
{
  ...,
  "5382778889": {
  "name": "Praça dos Heróis",
  "coordinates": {
    "latitude": -25.9351311,
    "longitude": 32.5792925
  },
  "street": "Av. Acordos de Lusaka",
  "connections": [
    {
      "stop": 6797387579,
      "bus": 10046632,
      "path": [...]
    },
    {
      "stop": 6797387579,
      "bus": 10053951,
      "path": [...]
    },
    {
      "stop": 6797387579,
      "bus": 10053954,
      "path": [...]
    },
    {
      "stop": 6797387579,
      "bus": 10053956,
      "path": [...]
    },
    {
      "stop": 6797387579,
      "bus": 10070649,
      "path": [...]
    }
  ],
    "walking_connections": [
    {
      "stop": "5382778890"
    }
  ]
  },
  "5382778890": {
    "name": "Praça dos Heróis",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": -25.9351503,
      "longitude": 32.5794082
    },
    "street": "Av. Acordos de Lusaka",
    "connections": [
      {
        "stop": 5382778885,
        "bus": 10046631,
        "path": [...]
      },
      {
        "stop": 5382778885,
        "bus": 10053950,
        "path": [...]
      },
      {
        "stop": 5382778885,
        "bus": 10053955,
        "path": [...]
      },
      {
        "stop": 5382778885,
        "bus": 10070980,
        "path": [...]
      },
      {
        "stop": 5382778885,
        "bus": 10102978,
        "path": [...]
      }
    ],
    "walking_connections": [
      {
        "stop": "5382778889"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

My djikstra algorithm looks like this:

```js
findPaths(stops, startPoint, endPoint) {
  const distance = {};
  const queue = new PriorityQueue();
  const previous = {};
  const buses = {};
  const visited = new Set();

  for (const stop in stops) {
    distance[stop] = stop == startPoint ? 0 : Infinity;
    queue.enqueue(stop, distance[stop]);
  };
  
  while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    const currentStop = Number(queue.dequeue());

    if (visited.has(currentStop)) {
      continue;
    };

    visited.add(currentStop);

    if (currentStop == endPoint) {
      const shortestPath = [];

      let stop = {
        stop: endPoint,
        name: stops[endPoint].name,
        coordinates: stops[endPoint].coordinates,
        street: stops[endPoint].street,
        path: [],
        bus: null,
      };

      while (stop) {
        shortestPath.unshift({...stop});
        stop = previous[stop.stop];
      };

      return shortestPath;
    };

    if (stops[currentStop] && stops[currentStop].connections) {
      for (const connection of stops[currentStop].connections) {
        const nextStop = connection.stop;
        const nextBus = connection.bus;
        const pathUsed = connection.path;

        let weight = 200;
        
        if (previous[currentStop] && previous[currentStop].bus) {
          if (nextBus == previous[currentStop].bus.id) {
            weight = 10;
          };
        };

        const newDistance = distance[currentStop] + weight;

        if (newDistance < distance[nextStop]) {
          distance[nextStop] = newDistance;

          previous[nextStop] = {
            stop: currentStop,
            name: stops[currentStop].name,
            coordinates: stops[currentStop].coordinates,
            street: stops[currentStop].street,
            path: pathUsed,
            bus: this.BusUseCase.getBusById(nextBus),
          };

          queue.enqueue(nextStop, newDistance);
        };
      };
    };

    if (stops[currentStop].walking_connections) {
      for (const connection of stops[currentStop].walking_connections) {
        const nextStop = connection.stop;
        const newDistance = distance[currentStop] + (stops[currentStop].name !== stops[nextStop].name ? 50 : 0);

        if (newDistance < distance[nextStop]) {
          distance[nextStop] = newDistance;
          previous[nextStop] = {
            stop: currentStop,
            name: stops[currentStop].name,
            coordinates: stops[currentStop].coordinates,
            street: stops[currentStop].street,
            path: [],
            bus: null,
          };

          queue.enqueue(nextStop, newDistance);
        };
      };
    };
  };

  return [];
};
```

Comment: It's Dijkstra (ij).

Comment: Please provide sample input (avoid things like `[...]` or `...,`, which is not valid), and the output you expect for it.

Comment: For each pair of nodes, throw away all parallel edges except the shortest one.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but from what is visible, it's likely you are modeling the problem wrong. Dijkstra's algorithm assumes that the weight of edges is fixed. In reality, buses don't depart every minute, so the time to travel between two stops also depends on the time of arrival. Finding an optimal bus schedule involves figuring a way to minimize the sum of the time spent in transit and the time waiting for the next connection. You can actually calculate this with Dijkstra's algorithm if you model this as a graph where vertices (time, stop) pairs, rather than just the stops.

Comment: @MaksVerver Not really. Since you visit each edge exactly once, and by the time you visit it you already know your arrival time to its source vertex, you can calculate the weight on the fly as your wait time plus travel time.

Comment: Imagine that I have stop A to stop Z in order, and I have the following buses: 
- Bus 1 can go from stop A to stop J 
- Bus 2 can go from stop A to stop I
- Bus 3 can go from stop I to stop Z

If I wanna go to stop J from stop A, the optimal path would be using bus 1, but sometimes, my algorithm can suggest me 2 buses. Example: Using bus 2 from stop A to stop I, the bus 3 from stop I to stop J.

This becomes a multigraph because the stop A (node) is connected with stop B using two different edges, the bus 1 and bus 2.

Answer (score 0):

Where a node has the choice of choosing between different buses, split the node into several, with zero cost connections between them and one bus per node.

e.g

```
u -> via BusA -> v
u -> via BusB -> v
```

becomes

```
u1 -> u2
u1 -> via BusA -> v
u2 -> via BusB -> v
```

Dijkstra will now have no problem finding its way around this graph and you can prune out the zero cost hops from the path.

Comment: Your suggestion works to rewrite a multigraph to a simple directed graph, but I don't think this directly addresses the problem OP has. Dijkstra's algorithm works perfectly well with multigraphs (you end up taking the shortest edges only). If they get the wrong answer it's probably because they've made a mistake somewhere else.